# How to implement a post link in core PHP?

Tags: php, hyperlink, edit

I have a link to edit a user say like below

http://project.com/user/edit?usrId=10

this link is in user view page. On click of the above link it takes the user to user edit page with user id = 10.

But problem what i am facing is, in the edit page if i simply change the id from 10 to say 20 the user with user id 20 data can be changed. I want to restrict this. Some sort of post link i want to implement in user view page only.

Similar to POST link in CAKE PHP.

How can i do this in core PHP?

Comment: Simply implement some authentication and authorization checks in your application.  It's impossible to be more specific than that, as you have provided no information to help you.

Comment: this link appear after login? if so then store user id in session and check that session id and get id are same or not.

Comment: Down votes may discourage people from asking question.We can probably add comments on how they can improve(Atleast for a new user). We all were newbies some day!!

Answer (score 2):

You have to implement some encryption/decryption technique for that
Check this link [Simple PHP multi way encryption method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10536664/looking-for-simple-php-multi-way-encryption-method)

Encrypt the user id 10 and pass it to the link and decrypt it in the edit page.

Answer (score 0):

Use some encryption for your variable that you are passing.PHP has functions like `base64_encode` and `base64_decode` which sends the variable in an encoded format.When you  receive the values on the edit page page,the the variable using `base64_decode($_GET('variable you sent through URL');`.
Also,when you send variables through URL strings they are prone to **injections**.Try to use PHP functions like `mysql_real_escape_strings` or `stripslashes` to avoid them from any possible attack.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

compare the passed in userid against the current userid for equality and redirect if they don't match