# Encrypting urls in zend

Tags: zend-framework

In my zend project I am passing parameters through urls to my controller. Since they appear in the HTML code, it is easy to figure out what values am I passing and for what purpose. Though I can use router to change the url but still the values will show up in the HTML script. I want to encrypt all my URLs from a security perspective. I am not able to understand how to use Zend encryption to encrypt and decrypt URLs. If anybody can help me with a tested sample code for the same and and not just pseudo I will be thankful.

Comment: http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/?

Comment: What sorts of things are you wanting to pass in the URL? If you are wanting to encrypt them 'from a security perspective' they probably shouldn't be in the URL in the first place, but if you can give examples we may be able to suggest an alternative approach.

Comment: I'm not even sure what you want is feasible.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a encryption/decryption technique for the parameter values.
Here is a [Simple PHP multi way encryption method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10536664/looking-for-simple-php-multi-way-encryption-method)
You can even encrypt the get parameters too. But it can be a PITA and the url would look horrible. But i dont think you can encrypt the `module/controller/action` part in the url.