# Deprecated: Function mcrypt_decrypt() in php

Tags: php, encryption, public-key-encryption, mcrypt

I update my server from 5.45 to 7.1 after that I am getting an error.
I am getting the issue in `decryptIt function`.

```
function encryptIt( $q ) {
    $cryptKey  = 'qJB0rGtIn5UB1xG03efyCp';
    $qEncoded      = base64_encode( mcrypt_encrypt( MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5( $cryptKey ), $q, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5( md5( $cryptKey ) ) ) );
    return( $qEncoded );
}

function decryptIt( $q ) {
    $cryptKey  = 'qJB0rGtIn5UB1xG03efyCp';
    $qDecoded      = rtrim( mcrypt_decrypt( MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5( $cryptKey ), base64_decode( $q ), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5( md5( $cryptKey ) ) ), "\0");
    return( $qDecoded );
}
```

I am encrypting the id using below code so that I can display the URL something like this `uYxnJrS3aLv0JbJFLnnmW4TRRpF6%2FYB0JD6LUhPYu0U%3D#`

```
$p_id=10;
$encrypted_user_id1 = encryptIt($p_id);
$p_user_id1=urlencode($encrypted_user_id1);
```

And decrepting it so that I will get the `$p_id=10` on my page

```
$decrypted_p_id = decryptIt($p_id);
```

But I am getting error now

```
Deprecated: Function mcrypt_decrypt() is deprecated
```

Would you help me out in this?

Comment: PHP has made this function, `mcrypt_decrypt`, deprecated since PHP 7.1.0. This is their official message: "Warning
This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 7.1.0. Relying on this function is highly discouraged."

Comment: I thought the error was quite clear.  The function is deprecated, don't use it.

Comment: I suggest using an already existing project, [AES encryption](https://aesencryption.net) is a great project

Comment: @LukePark, You are right, the error was quite clear. Is there any other option to encrypt the Id in the URL and decrypt it on the page?

Comment: Use `openssl_decrypt` instead

Comment: @LukePark, Ok I will try this.

Comment: @NarendraVerma - It was news to me too :s, ive just gone through all my answers which used the function and updated them, if you want an example here is one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10536664/looking-for-simple-php-multi-way-encryption-method/10536780#10536780

Comment: @LawrenceCherone, Thanks, I tested and working. I just need to know for a more secure form where I will get the PrivateKey and SecretKey?

Comment: If it helped ill be waiting for an upvote `;p`.. kidding, The `PrivateKey` is like your `md5($cryptKey)` but you pass it as a param, or change it in the function construct. `SecretKey` is the same as your double `md5(md5($cryptKey))`. It's not more or less secure, as CBC is CBC.

Comment: Yes, done for an upvote, Thanks for your help

Comment: Thanks, if you're looking for something more secure/flexible have a look at https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib

Comment: @LawrenceCherone, Thanks for the reply. I just want to use in the URL and sometime in password

Comment: I posted a full answer for PHP7.3 on the linked question https://stackoverflow.com/a/53937314/243782