# PHP openssl_decrypt returns strange output about 10% of the time

Tags: php, encryption, php-openssl

Using all the knowledge I could find on the internet I came up with a salt openssl encrypt and decrypt function. It works 90% of the time but every once in a wile the decrypt returns wither an empty sting or random bytes that have nothing to do with the encrypted data. The code I'm using is:

```
function Encrypt($subject, $method, $saltLength, $key){
    if($method==0){
        $salt=random_bytes($saltLength);
        $key=hash('sha256', $salt.$key);
        $iv=random_bytes(16);
        $encrypt=base64_encode(openssl_encrypt($subject, 'aes-256-ctr', $key, 0, $iv));
        $return=base64_encode("$method:$salt:$iv:$encrypt");
    }
    return($return);
}
function Decrypt($subject, $key){
    $components = explode( ':', base64_decode($subject));
    $method=$components[0];
    if($method==0){
        $salt=$components[1];
        $key = hash('sha256', $salt.$key);
        $iv=$components[2];
        $encrypt=base64_decode($components[3]);
        $return=(openssl_decrypt($encrypt, 'aes-256-ctr', $key, 0, $iv));
    }
    return($return);
}

$testE=Encrypt('Test', 0, 20, 'Key0');
var_dump($testE);
echo('<br><br>');
$testD=Decrypt($testE, 'Key0');
var_dump($testD);
echo('<br><br>');
$testD=Decrypt($testE, 'Key0');
var_dump($testD);
echo('<br><br>');
```

And an example of the faulty results for this code would be:

```
string(72) "MDrVsJAIE8OFjyM6y5dt+xkij5m/rTrHTnzeWs0IRrTKvNR1L7wfOmJrSlNRWFIzUFQwPQ==" 

string(1) "�" 

string(1) "�"
```

Or the return of a completely empty string:

```
string(72) "MDrQ+5c83vJXnva1OjrbJ2RWGjU5ajrwCn+qCneIIOqh48Gt0JmbOllsZFVUMHRuUFQwPQ==" 

string(0) "" 

string(0) ""
```

The reason I did the decrypt twice is to see if the fault is in the decrypt or the encrypt, the results clearly show that the encrypt is faulty in some way.

My question is what is causing this faulty encryption of the data? & can I improve this method and make it even more secure ?

Comment: You might want to base64 encode each part, your salt or iv may produce a `:`

Comment: Does this problem occur with the same data - ie: if you ran the encrypt/decrypt with the same initial data for 100 times would it be ok?

Comment: Yeah i think thats the problem `0:հÅ#:˗m":N|ZFʼu/:bkJSQXR3PT0=` is your decoded failed.

Comment: If you run the exact code given in the question 100 times the error occurs about 10 times, so the input data is the same

Comment: So I should base 64 encode my iv to prevent :?

Comment: can a sha256 hash also generate a  :  ?

Comment: ^ no, yeah base base64 encode each part, then your safe from `:`

Comment: out of curiosity what is the trouble with : in my encryption key

Comment: It not the correct way to implement ctr though. Why not just use cbt or ecb?

Comment: The problem is random_bytes could produce a `:`

Comment: oh I see and because I'm using : to explode my components they interfere, Thanks

Comment: Where can I find out what the difference between crt, cbt and ecb are ? Because I was wondering what the difference is to be honest

Comment: Its todo with the keystream internals https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/27776/block-chaining-modes-to-avoid/27780#27780, for the most part your code is just attempting to do basic encryption. it would be trivial to dissect it back out into its parts plus its adding more data by base64 encoding each part, around 33%, so cbc mode would be fine, you can create the iv from the key. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10536664/looking-for-simple-php-multi-way-encryption-method/10536780#10536780 if you want hmac verification or pbkdf2 then google alitle more there is many libs/ examples

Comment: *you can create the iv from the key* : well, yes, but only if you never reuse the key or if you've never followed a single lesson on cryptography before trying to employ it. CBC requires a random IV, certainly no a static one.

Comment: @ MaartenBodewes Never said the simple way was the best, If i gave you a an encrypted string and told you the mode, algo, salt, and iv etc everything *except* the key, I **guarantee** you would not be able to turn it into plaintext. You would need millions of encrypted examples to finally get the key.

Comment: Decrypt this: U09DUlR5TllGbXNKdVRWVHg2ZnNCQT09 - The same function in the link which was just downvoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While not the answer to why it is happening, oftentimes the result is what is most important.

If that is the case, then, if you get 90% accuracy, a while loop will quickly get you on your way.....

```
while(strlen($testD) < 5) {
    $testD=Decrypt($testE, 'Key0');
}
```

If your goal is to figure out what causes the minor faults, then you may have to look much deeper into the core code.  However, in my position, "get it done and move on" is often what the bosses say, so finding a working solution for gathering the info is often what I have to work with.